# returning data without first declaring array outside function

Tags: javascript

I have function that returns formatted chart data based on the selected day as per below, all works fine etc:

```
  const formatChartData = (data,myDate,myHour, myUnit, chartData) => {
    data.filter(
      addTakeDay > 0
      ? (item) => item[myDate].substring(0,10) === selectedDate
      : addTakeDay === 0
      ? (item) => item[myDate].substring(0,10) >= monday
      : (item) => item[myDate].substring(0,10) >= previousMonday && item[myDate].substring(0,10) < monday
      ).map((item) => {
        return {x: String(addTakeDay > 0
          ? (item[myHour].substring(11,13) < 10
              ? item[myHour].substring(12,13)
              : item[myHour].substring(11,13))
          : moment(item[myDate].substring(0,10),"YYYY-MM-DD").format("ddd")) ,y: item[myUnit]}
      }).reduce((res, value) => {
      if (!res[value.x]) {
          res[value.x] = { x: String(value.x), y: 0 };
          chartData.push(res[value.x])
      }
      res[value.x].y += value.y;
      return res;
      }, {});
  }


let myChartData = [];
formatChartData(dropIn,"ShiftDate","Hour","Units", myChartData)
```

My question is, is there a way to do this without first declaring the variable as an empty array outside the function. Can the function not do all the work? It's not major, I was just wondering really :)

Comment: `const myChartData = []` on the first line of the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very simple.

You need `function return value`
see this.

```js
  const formatChartData = (data,myDate,myHour, myUnit) => {
    const chartData = [];
    data.filter(
      addTakeDay > 0
      ? (item) => item[myDate].substring(0,10) === selectedDate
      : addTakeDay === 0
      ? (item) => item[myDate].substring(0,10) >= monday
      : (item) => item[myDate].substring(0,10) >= previousMonday && item[myDate].substring(0,10) < monday
      ).map((item) => {
        return {x: String(addTakeDay > 0
          ? (item[myHour].substring(11,13) < 10
              ? item[myHour].substring(12,13)
              : item[myHour].substring(11,13))
          : moment(item[myDate].substring(0,10),"YYYY-MM-DD").format("ddd")) ,y: item[myUnit]}
      }).reduce((res, value) => {
      if (!res[value.x]) {
          res[value.x] = { x: String(value.x), y: 0 };
          chartData.push(res[value.x])
      }
      res[value.x].y += value.y;
      return res;
      }, 
    {});
    return chartData;
  }

let myChartData = formatChartData(dropIn,"ShiftDate","Hour","Units", myChartData);
```

Comment: awesome thank you! it was the return value alluding me :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using chart data anywhere else just pass an empty array. you don't need to add a reference to it.

```
formatChartData(dropIn,"ShiftDate","Hour","Units", [])
```